# Multi-Container WebApp with Az.Websites

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

Is it possible to create a multi-container webApp through PowerShell using the [Az Module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az/5.6.0)? I saw that there are some examples with AzureCLI [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-multi-container#create-a-docker-compose-app), but I can't find anything related to Az.

Comment: Does the below answer help you?

Comment: Not necessarily. I did read the docs before asking here. It just amazes me that Azure CLI and Az PowerShell are not in sync. This kinda forces me to have a mix of both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Till now, it has not been rolled out. Check out `New-AzWebApp` definitions as per latest [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/new-azwebapp?view=azps-5.6.0):

```
New-AzWebApp
   [[-ResourceGroupName] <String>]
   [-Name] <String>
   [[-Location] <String>]
   [[-AppServicePlan] <String>]
   [-ContainerImageName <String>]
   [-EnableContainerContinuousDeployment]
   [-AsJob]
   [-GitRepositoryPath <String>]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [-WhatIf]
   [-Confirm]
   [<CommonParameters>]

New-AzWebApp
   [-ResourceGroupName] <String>
   [-Name] <String>
   [[-Location] <String>]
   [[-AppServicePlan] <String>]
   -ContainerImageName <String>
   -ContainerRegistryUrl <String>
   -ContainerRegistryUser <String>
   -ContainerRegistryPassword <SecureString>
   [-EnableContainerContinuousDeployment]
   [-AsJob]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [-WhatIf]
   [-Confirm]
   [<CommonParameters>]

New-AzWebApp
   [-ResourceGroupName] <String>
   [-Name] <String>
   [-Location] <String>
   [[-AppServicePlan] <String>]
   [[-SourceWebApp] <PSSite>]
   [[-TrafficManagerProfile] <String>]
   [-EnableContainerContinuousDeployment]
   [-IgnoreSourceControl]
   [-IgnoreCustomHostNames]
   [[-AppSettingsOverrides] <Hashtable>]
   [[-AseName] <String>]
   [[-AseResourceGroupName] <String>]
   [-IncludeSourceWebAppSlots]
   [-AsJob]
   [-DefaultProfile <IAzureContextContainer>]
   [-WhatIf]
   [-Confirm]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: What is the Azure powershell way of
`az webapp create --resource-group myResourceGroup --plan myAppServicePlan --name <app_name> --multicontainer-config-type compose --multicontainer-config-file compose-wordpress.yml`